# “probably was” or “probably would be”, which one is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

1. That probably was the most surprising moment in my life.
2. That probably would be the most surprising moment in my life.

Which of the above sentence is correct or are they both correct?  Is the second one just saying that I am just a little less certain whereas the first one saying I am a little more sure?

Comment: Please can you add any research you've done and why you think your conclusion is correct?

Comment: Are you talking about something (potentially) in the past, or in the future?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IMO neither is correct, because of the word order.

Also the word [**probably**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/probably)  includes a slight uncertainty, otherwise you would say [**definitely**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/definitely).

I suggest:

> That was probably the most surprising moment in my life.

---

Edit (following a comment from OP).

If you aren't very certain you can use another adverb:

> That was [**possibly**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/possibly) the most surprising moment in my life.

or

> That was one of the more surprising moments in my life.

Comment: that seems a little confident, i want to sound more uncertain and doubtful

Comment: Then don't use the word **probably** which means "fairly certainly." I have edited the answer.

Comment: could you explain why this sentence is wrong  'that probably would be the most surprising moment in my life'

Comment: Because the word order is incorrect: "that would probably be the most surprising moment in my life."