# "would probably be" or "would be probably"?

Tags: meaning, tense

In my other question (["The question is that" vs. "The question is"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240010/109190)) I said

> I guess the 3rd way ... **would be probably** grammatical and idiomatic.

where I used "would be probably", as I remember my grammar teacher told me that the adverb should be after the verb to be and all auxiliary verbs.

After I posted that question, I realized that "would probably be" fits with the rule as well.

And then I searched a bit on ELL, ["would be probably" got 10 hits](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22would%20be%20probably%22), ["would probably be" got 454 hits](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22would%20probably%20be%22). Which seems to indicate that the former might be no as common.

Is my understanding right? Are both expressions grammatical and idiomatic?

When I was writing this post, ELL recommended another one ([“probably was” or “probably would be”, which one is correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/222470/109190)), which mentions "probably would be" that turns out to be incorrect due to the wrong placement of adverb.